# Is watchdog timer still working in sleep mode?

Tags: embedded, watchdog, zigbee

I'm using Zigbee to build up a net.The platform core is CC2530. I want to use its power mode 2 (sleep)for power saving and watchdog at the same time. However,in sleep mode, **most of** the module will be shut down. Is watchdog timer still working in sleep mode?(I've checked datasheet up already.)

Comment: If you're putting the entire device to sleep (e.g. no radio operations), then put the device into a mode where the watch dog is run off an external crystal (32kHz). I believe the 32MHz clock is required for radio operations.

Answer (score 2):

There's not a clear statement in the [*User's Guide*](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/swru191f/swru191f.pdf) however the clock source used by the Watchdog timer is enabled in PM2 (32KHz) so I'm expecting that Watchdog is enabled.

Given that the maximum Watchdog period is 1s, you can use PM3 (that disable all internal clocks) when you need a longer sleep period.